# Compact methods to verify that a set with binary operation/s is a group or ring or module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules

My instructor for abstract algebra explained that in order to show that $(G, \star)$ is a group over the set $G$ all we have to do is verify that the identity is in G and that for $a, b \in G$ we have $a\star b^{-1} \in G$

Is there a similarly compact way to verify that $(R, +, \times)$ is a ring over the set $R$? What about verifying that $M$ is a left (or right) $R-$module for a ring $R$?

I suspect the answer to this question will be more nuanced for modules since there is a conjugation map and a homomorphism happening but I am not sure for either modules or rings if there is a more compact method than independently verifying each part of the definitions.

Comment: To show that $G$ is a group you still have to verify for associativity, unless $G$ is a subset of another group.

Comment: Thank you, so this compact verification method is 1.) show the identity exist with usual rules, 2.) show $a \star b^{-1} \in G$, 3.) show $a\star (b\star c) =  (a\star b)\star c$? That makes sense.

Comment: I still do not think that it is correct. Because stating $a \star b^{-1}\in G$ means that you had assumed $b^{-1}$ must exist but this is not true in general again, unless it is a subset of another group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a compact test for determining if a nonempty set *is a subgroup of a group*.

The proposed test does not guarantee associativity of the product, so it is incomplete.

However, when applied to a subgroup, associativity is inherited from the supergroup (which is a group by assumption), so it is not an issue.

---

The analogue for rings would be a *subring test* where you first check if $(S,+)< (R,+)$ using the criterion above ($a-b\in S$ for all $a,b\in S$) and then you make sure it is closed under multiplication ($ab\in S$ for $a,b\in S$.)

Perhaps more importantly, the latter can be extended to be test to see *if a nonempty subset is an ideal* if the last condition is replaced with $ar,ra\in S$ for every $a\in S$, and $r\in R$.

---

I think at this point you can probably work out the analogue for modules yourself.